# Duda sobre SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Con la instrucción INSERT INTO–SELECT, crear una tabla con el nombre Alumno2012 en donde se almacenen aquellos alumnos que tengan el carnet del año 2012

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
create table [Alumno2012](
Carnet char(8) not null,
NombreCompleto varchar(50)
constraint pk_alumno1 primary key (Carnet)
)
```

Pero cuando realizo la consulta me dice que 0 filas han sido afectadas, no sé a que se deba ese error, la consulta es la siguiente:

```
insert into [Alumno2012]
select Carnet, substring(Carnet, 3,4) as Carnet2012
from alumno
where Carnet = '12'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado el select `select Carnet, substring(Carnet, 3,4) as Carnet2012 from alumno where Carnet = '12'`, que te da como resultado? si te regresa 0 registros allí esta el problema, no encuentra ningún Carnet = '12'

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo Como podria entonces la comparación para que obtenga los alumnos que tengan carnet del 2012?

Comment: Qué tipo de dato es Carnet? y que datos tienes en tu base de datos?, no podría decirte como poner el filtro correcto en tu query si no se la estructura de tu tabla :-S

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta un ejemplo de tu base de datos, puede ser una imagen con algunos registros y el tipo de dato que es el campo Carnet?

Comment: A ya se cual es el detalle, en el where tendrias que tener el substring algo asi: where substring(Carnet, 3,4) = '12'

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo listo, ya esta la imagen

Comment: de esta manera?


insert into [Alumno2012]
select Carnet, NombreCompleto
from alumno
where substring(Carnet, 3,4) = '12'

Comment: Primero asegúrate de que `substring(Carnet, 3,4)` este seleccionando los datos del año, para eso puedes validarlo con un `select substring(Carnet, 3,4)..`

Comment: Si como lo tienes, pero primero antes del insert valida el select: `select Carnet, NombreCompleto from alumno where substring(Carnet, 3,4) = '12'`, para que veas que te regresa los datos esperados, igual puedes poner substring en el select para validar que traiga el dato del año y ajustarlo de ser necesario, osea que en lugar de 3,4 sea 2,3 algo asi... si me explico?

Comment: Otra pregunta Carnet en que posición esta el año?  CD**12**1215 <-- ese es el año?

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo si la parte negrita que has puesto es el año, entonces la posicion que yo le habia optado era como 3,2

Comment: Puedes validarlo haciendo el select: `select top 50 substring(Carnet, 3,4) ,Carnet, NombreCompleto from alumno ` y compara la columna1 de este select con la columna Carnet fijate si se esta tomando el dato correcto

Comment: Ok ya vi otro detalle deberías usar `SUBSTRING(carnet,3,2)`, substring funciona así: el primer numero es la posición y el segundo numero es la longitud

Comment: Lo estoy usando de la manera en que me has dicho, si me toma el dato correcto, pero ahora el error me dice esto

**Violación de la restricción PRIMARY KEY 'pk_alumno1'. No se puede insertar una clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.Alumno2012'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (12).**

Comment: Yap, el substring ponlo en el where solamente, no lo pongas en el select:
`insert into [Alumno2012]
select Carnet, substring(Carnet, 3,4) as Carnet2012
from alumno
where SUBSTRING(carnet,3,2)= '12'`

Comment: Debes rediseñar esa tabla para tener el año como una columna independiente. Es parte de la normalización y hacerlo te ayudará a prevenir problemas en el futuro. Ningún dato debe usarse para identificar un atributo si es sólo un segmento de otro atributo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que actualmente tu condición de filtro NO cumple con la regla determinada `(=12)`. Lo que necesitas es que sea igual al tercer y cuarto carácter de tu cadena de texto, que según entiendo se ubica el año para el formato de carnet utilizado.

```
insert into [Alumno2012]
select Carnet, Carnet as Carnet2012
from alumno
where SUBSTRING(Carnet,3,2)
```

Otro de los problemas que generaría tu instrucción es que estas duplicando claves primarias (al estar intentando insertar solo el año). Deberías simplemente pasar el campo carnet a secas.